# C++ Arrays of Structures

Tags: arrays, c++11, struct

in my endeavors to learn C++, I have come accross a lesson I don't understand. It is: creating arrays of structs, or creating arrays of type struct. I can't seem to understand how they work. Could someone please explain it to me, or redirect me to a good tutorial? I have looked myself, but can't find anything that explains well. Thank you.

Comment: Did you have the lesson about arrays? Did you have the lesson about structs? Try to combine that.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an array using a struct as the type, instead of an int or some other primitive type. For example:

```
int intArray[size];
struct myStruct structArray[size];
```

You can fill `intArray` with `size` `int` values, and reference them with `intArray[i]`. Likewise, each address in `structArray` can hold a `struct myStruct`, and can be referenced with `structArray[i]`.

Comment: This looks and feels very much `C` and not `C++`

Comment: Structs can be used in C++ the same as in C, and he spoke of arrays in his question, not vectors or any other container object. So I answered based on what I thought he was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are learning C++, I suggest start using STL and containers.

Say you have a Car structure:

```
struct Car {
    std::string color;
    int wheels;
};
```

Now if you have more than one car you want to work with, you make an array of cars:

```
std::vector<Car> cars;
Car car1;
car1.color = "yellow";
Car car2;
car2.color = "green";
// Add the cars to your vector
cars.push_back(car1);
cars.push_back(car2);
// You are not limited to the number of cars.
// You can check how many cars you have:
int nrCars = cars.size();
```

Say you want to work with the first car:

```
std::cout << "Color of first car is: " << cars[0].color;
std::cout << "Color of second car is: " << cars[1].color;
// Make sure not to go past the number of cars, like cars[5]
```

If you want to loop over the cars:

```
 for(int idx = 0; idx < cars.size(); ++idx) {
    std::cout << "Car nr " << idx << " is: " << cars[idx].color;
 }
```